# Permissions in Laravel - ACL vs Middleware

Tags: laravel, acl, user-permissions, laravel-middleware

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the proper times to use ACL or middleware in Laravel. I do understand the examples on their site and Laracasts, but they're rather simple examples.

This isn't anymore complicated by any means, but I didn't see examples for these. Let's say I have two routes that allow a user to create a task. The first being the `GET` request to fill out the information, and the second being the `POST` to store the information. There are some users that are not allowed to create tasks based on their role. In both cases, there isn't a particular object that exists, which is what the ACL requires as far as I understand. So would I use middleware for something like that? And when an object exists, use ACL for that?

An alternative I've been trying to fit in is the use of Form Requests too, but then I'd have to create a Form Request object for each route (although I don't really mind personally).

What is a good approach to limiting acccess to actions, when there isn't a specific action to act upon?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Notice**: I was going to post this as a comment, but it got a little too extent. Feel free to wait for better answers and maybe consider this just a comment.

I think that you're missing the whole point here. You can have a `middleware` that consults the ACL or you can use the `FormRequest` to consult the ACL or use each of them separately. For instance, at the `authorize` method of the  `CreateTaskRequest`, you can check the ACL to see if the user has the proper role to create a task.

You might be getting too hooked up when Jeff tries to check if the user `owns` the post. That kind of ACL is record-oriented, but you can have a role that just takes the user as a parameter (and no other entity) and see if that user just has a specific role. By returning true, the action is authorized, otherwise it's denied.

A middleware have more to do with the route instead of the request. You can also have a middleware that gets the authenticated user and check if it has the role to create a task. Those are different ways to achieve the same thing (which is one of the benefits of Laravel, having lots of ways to achieve the same goal).

Your specific action to act upon is the "Create new Task" action. Who do you want to be able to do that? Users that have the role manager? Users that have the permission `create-task`?

At the end of the day, what I would consider is:

- Are there lots of routes that will have the same rule? Maybe a middleware would be a good choice.
- Are there specific rules for each kind of operation? Can an user that did not create a task be able to edit one? Form Requests might be easier to achieve this kind of specification
- Which `$this` environment would make my life easier? `$this` from the `Form Request` or `$this` from a middleware?

One thing I learned from Jeff's class are that he teaches too much cool stuff and sometimes I end up missing one point or two. Try re-watching the basic steps again and maybe stop when you think you found something that would work. Then implement that and see what your case differs from his and how you think he'd write that feature.